# Get the least greater than value from python list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, lambda

## What I want to achieve?

I have the following list of dictionaries.

```
values=[
   {
    "tax": 6,
    "threshold": 1000
  },
  {
    "tax": 9,
    "threshold": 2500
  },
  {
    "tax": 14,
    "threshold": 7500
  }
]
```

I want to get the least value of tax, applicable to some amount which is greater than or equal to the value. Let's say:

If my amount is 1100 and I compare it to the threshold of these dicts. I should get the value of `tax = 9`.

## What I've been able to do so far?

```
floor_value = map(lambda x: x.get("tax") if x.get(
        "threshold") > 1000 else None, values)
print (floor_value)

output:
[None, 9, 14]
```

What I want is `floor_value = 9`

Comment: Are the dictionaries ordered? If yes: `next(x.get('tax') for x in values if x.get('threshold') > 1000)` would be a solution.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta No, they're not ordered dictionaries.

Comment: well what you're doing there is pretty complicated for a simple task. Your problem is that you're mapping and outputting the whole dictionary. There are simpler ways to achieve what you want

Comment: @Shinratensei I agree but I want a one/two liner approach to the problem coz my code has increased and this is just a bit of what I'm doing. So I'm finding as concise way as possible.

Comment: @JaysheelUtekar Then you could simply do `min(<your_solution>)` assuming taxes increase with thresholds... this is generally true in the real world

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta I already did it but because of this `if x.get(
        "threshold") > 1000 else None` i always get None for values greater than 1000. Because the map gives me `[None, 9, 14]` for amount values which are greater than 1000. Or I can do something like floor_value.remove(None) and then do `min(floor_value)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach.

**Demo:**

```
values = [{'tax': 6, 'threshold': 1000}, {'tax': 9, 'threshold': 2500}, {'threshold': 7500, 'tax': 14}]
v = 1100 

def getValue(values, v):
    for i in sorted(values, key=lambda x: x["threshold"]):   #Sort list by threshold
        if i["threshold"] >= v:     #Compare
            return i["tax"]         #Return

print(getValue(values, v))
```

**Output:**

```
9
```

Comment: You should not need to sort as this problem can be solved in 0(n)

Answer (score 0):

I really hate that kind of one liner and I advice you to not use it for your problem.

```
import functools
functools.reduce(lambda x,y : y if 1100 < y['threshold'] < x['threshold'] else x,
                 values,
                 {'threshold' : float('inf')}
                )['tax']
```

Raises a KeyError if no entry matches the conditions

This works too but needs a bit more operations (still O(n), needs to iterate over the filtered list to find the min):

```
min([(v['threshold'], v['tax']) for v in values if v['threshold'] > 1100])[1]
```

raises Error too if nothing matches

This is the solution you should do (or similar):

```
result = None
for value in values:
    threshold = value['threshold']
    if threshold > 1100 and (not result or threshold < result['threshold']):
        result = value
print(result['tax'])
```

because I don't agree with

> @Shinratensei I agree but I want a one/two liner approach to the problem coz my code has increased and this is just a bit of what I'm doing. So I'm finding as concise way as possible.

Answer (score -1):

Your data structure is not helpful for what you are trying to do. Modify it like this:

```
values=[
   {
    "tax": 6,
    "entry_value": 0,
    "threshold": 1000
  },
  {
    "tax": 9,
    "entry_value": 1000,
    "threshold": 2500
  },
  {
    "tax": 14,
    "entry_value": 2500,
    "threshold": 7500
  }
]
```

Then you can do

```
>>> number = 1100
>>> [d["tax"] for d in values if d["entry_value"] < number <= d["threshold"]]
[9]
```

But this will only work if you spell *threshold* consistently.

Comment: 1) You don't need `entry_value` just `zip(values, values[1:])` 2) This solution breaks when the amount is `1000.5`

Answer (score -2):

I noticed there is a naming error with the dictionaries. "threshhold" and "threshold" but the solution here works.

```
min_value = 1000

floor_value =  min([x.get("tax") for x in values if x.get("threshhold", 0) > min_value])

print(floor_value)
```

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with "naming error", your answer is wrong.